# How to make the Stackblitz angular 6.0.6 find "primeng" modules? (primeng 6.0.0 added as dependency)

Tags: angular, primeng, stackblitz

I added primeng (6.0.0) as dependency in Stackblitz (Angular 6.0.6) and tried to import primeng modules (e.g. TreeModule) but it doesn't find it, you may see the code in below stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wqef8y

The [app.module.ts](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wqef8y?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts) can't find primeng modules.

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just the intelisense does not find the module for some reason and gives an error. Else the code works if you import the TreeModule in the AppModule.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';

import {TreeModule} from 'primeng/tree';


@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, BrowserAnimationsModule, TreeModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Here is a fork of your stakblitz example that I fixed to work. [StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9ylrko) It still shows the error in the editor. I have also added the styles in the styles.css file so it displays correctly.

Comment: just to add as you did, adding the styles are necessary too :: @ import url("../node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css");
@ import "~primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css";
@ import "~primeng/resources/primeng.min.css";